# dnsmasq fails to answer queries on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, dnsmasq

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 dnsmasq fails to answer quires from subnets other then it's interfaces belong to.  I wonder if there is an option that allows to add trusted subnets?
Here is the log message
`Ignoring query from non-local network`

Comment: very similar question: https://superuser.com/q/1255211/208765

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [v2.69 changelog](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/CHANGELOG):

```
    Add --local-service. Accept DNS queries only from hosts 
        whose address is on a local subnet, ie a subnet for which 
        an interface exists on the server. This option
        only has effect if there are no --interface --except-interface,
        --listen-address or --auth-server options. It is intended 
        to be set as a default on installation, to allow
        unconfigured installations to be useful but also safe from 
        being used for DNS amplification attacks.
```

So, the fix is to make sure you don't have the local-service option in any conf files (including any pre-installed ones such as in /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf) and include one of the above listed options in your conf file. E.g. `--interface=eth0`.

Comment: with no --local-service option it will answer any requests, I need an option that allows me to white list some subnets.

Comment: Check the [man page](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/08/26/yahoo_starts_199_watch_list_to_recycle_old_usernames/), there are options to exclude certain interfaces from listening. I don't know how you can exclude responses to certain networks though. You may need to do that with iptables and probably warrants a different question, rather than discussing it here.

Comment: @Darren You say it's necessary to «*make sure you don't have the local-service option in any conf files (including any pre-installed ones such as in /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf)*», but it isn't. The man page says: `This option only has effect if there are no --interface --except-interface, --listen-address or --auth-server options`.

BTW, to listen on all interfaces, use `--interface=*`.

Comment: @myrdd, OK, well this was over a year ago so I can't tell you what my line of thinking was. Possible I mis-read something.

Comment: @Darren okay, I felt free to edit your answer to reflect my suggestion. (hope this is ok.)

Comment: @myrdd Yes, that's fine.

Comment: This also happen on Ubuntu 18.04. Edit the `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq` and remove `--local-service` from `DNSMASQ_OPTS` variable to fix it.

Comment: Is there a way to make it answer non-local queries even when using `--interface`?