# DNSMASQ not answering DNS queries from routed subnet

Tags: networking, dnsmasq

I have two sub-nets connected together using two DD-WRT APs - The remote AP is in 
Client-Routed mode so it has a separate subnet its IP are 192.168.2.1/24 and 192.168.0.5/24.  The local AP is in AP mode
The DD-WRT DHCP settings are in forward mode for the remote AP

I have DNSMASQ setup within the first subnet on IP 192.168.0.2/24 it is also the DHCP server for the second subnet - this works and my remote clients get the correct router.  The DNSMasq machine can ping the PC on the second subnet and the reverse is also true
I can also RDP from a PC on the first subnet to the PC on the second subnet - so it appears to me most of the first to second subnet comms is working

My problem is DNSMasq does not send DNS replies to the second subnet - it does work to the first subnet.  Can anyone suggest why?

One thing to note is that the route for the second network was on the gateway device (192.168.0.1 ) but I found this dropped many packets - so each of the first sub-net devices has a local static route for the second subnet added to it.

```
route add 192.168.2.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.5
```

I've yet to test the DHCP assigned route at this point due to my current problem

This is a sketch of what I have [image: Sketch network]

DNSMASQ Config

```
# Configuration file for dnsmasq.
domain-needed
bogus-priv
addn-hosts=/etc/dnsmasq.hosts
# so don't use it if you use eg Kerberos, SIP, XMMP or Google-talk. This option only affects forwarding, SRV records originating for dnsmasq (via srv-host= lines) are not
# suppressed by it.
filterwin2k

dhcp-range=set:house,192.168.0.1,192.168.0.254,infinite
dhcp-range=set:backyard,192.168.2.1,192.168.2.254,infinite

# Change this line if you want dns to get its upstream servers from somewhere other that /etc/resolv.conf
resolv-file=/var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf
# server=61.9.134.49
# server=61.9.133.193 setup the default gateway
dhcp-option=tag:house,option:router,192.168.0.1
dhcp-option=tag:backyard,option:router,192.168.2.1

# option 42?
dhcp-option=option:ntp-server,192.168.0.2
expand-hosts
domain=wilson.lan
dhcp-range=192.168.0.100,192.168.0.150,12h
dhcp-range=192.168.2.100,192.168.2.150,255.255.255.0,12h


# DO NOT Set The route to that network Done on Gateway
#dhcp-option=121,192.168.2.0/24,192.168.0.5
#Send microsoft-specific option to tell windows to release the DHCP lease when it shuts down. Note the "i" flag,
#  to tell dnsmasq to send the value as a four-byte integer - that's what microsoft wants. See
# http://technet2.microsoft.com/WindowsServer/en/library/a70f1bb7-d2d4-49f0-96d6-4b7414ecfaae1033.mspx?mfr=true
dhcp-option=vendor:MSFT,2,1i
# Set the DHCP server to authoritative mode. In this mode it will barge in and take over the lease for any client
# which broadcasts on the network, whether it has a record
# of the lease or not. This avoids long timeouts when a machine wakes up on a new network.
# DO NOT enable this if there's the slightest chance that you might end up
# accidentally configuring a DHCP server for your campus/company accidentally.
# The ISC server uses the same option, and this URL provides more information:
# http://www.isc.org/files/auth.html
dhcp-authoritative
# Log lots of extra information about DHCP transactions.
log-dhcp
```

Comment: I also tried on the second subnet a nslookup from 8.8.8.8 and that works -

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok so after reading the manual better I need to add in something to override the default of only answer local sub-nets (--local-service) a default option which has no negation so for example I tried

```
listen-address=192.168.0.2
```

However as resolve.conf has the line

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

my change stopped DNSMASQ answering queries from itself  - so strangely enough the DNS server no longer could resolve any dns name whilst all other machines were successfully using it as a dns server.  I fixed this by adding the following line instead

```
listen-address=192.168.0.2,127.0.0.1
```

as I could not work out a simple way to fix what resolveconf was doing

Comment: The Arch Wiki mentions it, albeit somewhat vague on the details, here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dnsmasq

Comment: Thanks , I  didn't think of looking for articles in different flavours of Linux that does appear to tell me how to fix this original problem, also seems to say it's dhcpd is a possible culprit, although I'm not using that

Comment: I have a similar problem on Ubuntu 18.04 and it was fixed this way: Edit the `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq` and remove `--local-service` from `DNSMASQ_OPTS` variable to fix it.

Comment: Ah ... yes so that’s where defaults are stored

Comment: Setting `interfaces=*` also works. As stated in the [man](https://man.archlinux.org/man/dnsmasq.8)-page, `--local-service` only has effect when there are no `--interface`, `--except-interface`, `--listen-address` or `--auth-server` options.